# Jinja loop.index does not print

Tags: python, django, jinja2

When running the following jinja code, I only get "Column  info" printed. Why the index does not appears ?

```
{% for field in columns_form %}
    {% if 'title_' in field.name %}
        <td>Column {{ loop.index }} info</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the template definitely being treated as a Jinja template? I ask because `{{ loop.index }}` should work in a Jinja template, but wouldn't work in a Django template, where you would use `{{ forloop.counter  }}` instead. You haven't shown your view or `TEMPLATES` settings, so we can't tell whether you've configured your template engine correctly.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds like the template is being treated as a Django template, not a Jinja template.

Using `{{ loop.index }}` should work in a Jinja template, but wouldn't work in a Django template, where you would use `{{ forloop.counter }}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case `{{ loop.index }}` does not work in the latest version, a workaround is to zip the `columns_form` and `range(0, len(columns_form)+1)` in the python file as

```
columns_form_idx = zip(columns_form, range(0, len(columns_form)+1))
```

In the template file,

```
{% for field, idx in columns_form_idx %}
    {% if 'title_' in field.name %}
        <td>Column {{ idx }} info</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```